# How to template database in Airflow SQLExecuteQueryOperator

Tags: python, sql, airflow

I have an Airflow dag with a PostgresOperator to execute a SQL query. I want to switch to different database(using same connection) with config (run w/config). But it gives an error `database "{{ dag_run.conf['database'] }}" does not exist`

I try to create a custom postgresql operator with similar code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75187173/how-to-run-airflow-dag-with-conn-id-in-config-template-by-postgresoperator)

I added below code, but it gives me same error (not rendering template)

```
from airflow.providers.postgres.operators.postgres import PostgresOperator as _PostgresOperator
class PostgresOperator(_PostgresOperator):
    template_fields = [*_PostgresOperator.template_fields, "database"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PostgresOperator` is [deprecated](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/e01323635a88ecf313a415ea41d32d6d28fa0794/airflow/providers/postgres/operators/postgres.py#L78-L84). You should migrate to `SQLExecuteQueryOperator`.

The equivalent of `database` in `PostgresOperator` is schema in `SQLExecuteQueryOperator` as can be seen [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/e01323635a88ecf313a415ea41d32d6d28fa0794/airflow/providers/postgres/operators/postgres.py#L64).

Since `SQLExecuteQueryOperator` is generic operator it allows to pass the different hooks parameters with `hook_params`. However, `hook_params` is not a [templated field](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/e01323635a88ecf313a415ea41d32d6d28fa0794/airflow/providers/common/sql/operators/sql.py#L216) thus you should subclass  `SQLExecuteQueryOperator` to add it as templated field.

```
from airflow.providers.common.sql.operators.sql import SQLExecuteQueryOperator

class MySQLExecuteQueryOperator(SQLExecuteQueryOperator):
    template_fields: Sequence[str] = tuple({"hook_params"} | set(SQLExecuteQueryOperator.template_fields))


with DAG('sql_example', start_date=datetime(2023, 01, 1), schedule=None):

    MySQLExecuteQueryOperator(task_id='postgres',
                              conn_id='postgres_default',
                              sql="SELECT 1",
                              hook_params={"schema": "{{ ds }}"} # ds is not a valid schema just to show render works
                              )
```

Which will give:

[image]

Obviously `2023-07-28` is not a valid schema but this is just to show that rendering works.

Comment: Kinda unrelated to q but why don't they include all these params as a templated field? what's the downside?

Comment: @Gabe security and performance. Temapling basicly allows you to inject thus enabling everything by default may come with a risk (though this is debatable). Given that Airflow was built to be extended and extentions (like subclassing) is supper easy it seems like a good balance. As for perfoemance, templating is extra step needs to be done when task is executed thus more fields equals more time.